# Alternative to Cisco APIC-EM for small lab

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, lab, automation

Are there any alternatives to meet a small auto provisioning server for a Cisco switch (Cat3850)? I'm working to setting up a "plug and play" capable Cisco switch (Cat3850) in small isolated lab.  I unfortunate don't have access to the DevNet sandbox. I'm constrained for compute resources in this lab and the VM host requirements for the free APIC-EM download are a bit stiff.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you want a simple yes/no answer, but unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: If I amended my question to say something such as 'how to bootstrap lab cat3850?'

Comment: What sort of lab configuration do you have? There are ways to do this if you have the correct sort of equipment configured in the lab.

Comment: Small branch (ISR4451 with cat3850) connected via simulated ISP/DMVPN to HQ (ASR1002-X).  I'm trying to do a "lowest touch possible" switch deployment/provisioning. Ubuntu DNS/DHCP/syslog () system also configured to provide basic services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ISR and a DHCP server, but you need a TFTP server, then you can just use [SmartInstall for Zero Touch Switch Deployment](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3750-x-series-switches/white_paper_c11-651895.html):

> **Abstract**
>
> SmartInstall provides a suite of capabilities that help deploy new Cisco® Catalyst® switches and manage them effectively at
> very low operating costs. SmartInstall has true zero-touch switch
> installation to lower operational costs. SmartInstall helps with
> initial switch deployment, switch configuration management, and switch
> replacement. This document will explain the practical benefits of
> deploying SmartInstall, configurable options for deployment based on
> different network scenarios, best practices, and customization
> options.

Comment: Many thanks! Quick read and it definitely looks like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

[Catalyst SmartInstall for Zero Touch Switch Deployment](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3750-x-series-switches/white_paper_c11-651895.html)

> SmartInstall can enable plug-and-play configuration and image
>   management for zero-touch deployment on new and existing Cisco
>   Catalyst LAN switches and zero-touch replacement of existing switches
>   that need to be replaced in a return materials authorization (RMA)
>   scenario.

[Nexus 5000 PowerOn Auto Provisioning](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/fundamentals/513_n2_1/b_Cisco_Nexus_5000_Series_NX-OS_Fundamentals_Configuration_Guide_Release_513_N21/b_Cisco_Nexus_5000_Series_NX-OS_Fundamentals_Configuration_Guide_Release_5_1_3_N2_1_chapter_01001.html)

> PowerOn Auto Provisioning (POAP) automates the process of upgrading
>   software images and installing configuration files on Cisco Nexus
>   switches that are being deployed in the network for the first time.

[IOS Routers AutoInstall](http://AutoInstall)

> AutoInstall is supported over Ethernet, Token Ring, and FDDI
>   interfaces for LANs and serial interfaces with High-Level Data Link
>   Control (HDLC) encapsulation or serial interfaces with Frame Relay
>   encapsulation for WANs. If a LAN interface is used, AutoInstall will
>   attempt to acquire an IP address for the attached interface using
>   Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) requests, Bootstrap
>   Protocol (BOOTP) requests, or Reverse Address Resolution Protocol
>   (RARP) requests. If a serial interface with HDLC encapsulation is
>   connected, AutoInstall will attempt to acquire an IP address for the
>   attached interface using Serial Line Address Resolution Protocol
>   (SLARP).